# Permission based media server

Tags: python, django, jwt

I wanna build web based file/media(can be any type such as .mp4, .something) server using Django and JWT will handle the authorization. As normally, all media files are publicly accessible if we copy paste absolute path. How can setup in a way when only authorised user can access that specific file/media?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is overriding Django's media serve URL endpoint and modifying that function which handles serving.